# Multiple selection for document picker controller

Tags: ios, swift, multipleselection, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to select multiple files in document picker. Here is my code:

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeFolder)], in: .import)
documentPicker.delegate = self
self.present(documentPicker, animated: false) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    }
}
```

But it is selecting only 1 file at a time. Can anyone suggest me a correct way?

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it before

`self.present`

your code should be

```
 let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeFolder)], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
             documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
         }
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: false) {

        }
```

and check in Browse tab, not in Recenets tab

Comment: it goes to the folder only and also picker is not dismissed on clicking done button.

Comment: yep, you need to click open after you finish with selection. The done button just finish the selection.